# Get Input value from Inputbox inside ASP Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 3 templatefield columns. When the gridview is databound, an input text box is generated in the template fields where the placeholders are.

The question is, is it possible to get the values from the input boxes in the code-behind file on post back? Or does it need to be done client side with js?

This is a slimmed down version of the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3"
    DataSourceID="DS" Font-Size="X-Small" Width="100%" BackColor="White" CellSpacing="1"
    BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" 
    ShowFooter="True" ondatabound="GV_DataBound"
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SKILL" HeaderText="Skill" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="SKILL">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COMP_GEN" HeaderText="Competencies (General)" HtmlEncode="False"
            SortExpression="COMP_GEN">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designer Score">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat='server' ID="devGenDesScore"></asp:PlaceHolder>                        
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="devGenDesScoreTotal_txt" name="inputs" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#005293" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" BorderColor="Gray"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#253E51" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I've tried variations of this but can't get it to work:

```
TextBox compGenDesScoreTxt = GV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox;
int compGenDesScore = Convert.ToInt32(compGenDesScoreTxt.Text);
```

It throws this error on the `int compGenDesScore = Convert....` line:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is how I generate the inputBoxes:

```
protected void GV_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int c = GV.Columns.Count;
    int r = GV.Rows.Count;
    //Loop through each row
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        //Loop through each column on that row
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            //First competancy
            if (j == 2)
            {
                //Read the contents of the cell, if its blank, do nothing. If it has text, add a textbox for the score
                contents = GV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                if (contents != "&nbsp;")
                {
                    PlaceHolder placeHolder = GV.Rows[i].FindControl("devGenDesScore") as PlaceHolder;
                    TextBox devGenDesScore_txt = new TextBox();
                    devGenDesScore_txt.ID = "devGenDesScore_txt";
                    devGenDesScore_txt.Style.Add("width", "50px");
                    placeHolder.Controls.Add(devGenDesScore_txt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try finding the textbox control as, string x=((TextBox)GV.Rows[i].FindControl("devGenDesScore")).Text;

Comment: Throws the same error. Could be to do with the textbox ID's? I added more code in the question explaining how I'm generating the textfields

Comment: The ID you pass to `FindControl()` should be the ID you assigned the control when you created it. Try Anurag's code again, but with the correct ID.

Comment: When I tried Anurag's code I did use the ID assigned when the field was created ie `string x=((TextBox)GV.Rows[i].FindControl("devGenDesScore_txt")).Text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was to do with the databinding of the GV. I was using placeholders and then replacing them with input fields where needed. Instead of that, I put the input text fields straight into the template field in aspx page and set the visibility to false. Then, on the databind event I set the fields I needed to appear to true.

May help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

TextBox compGenDesScoreTxt = GV.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("controlID");